# Colocar header em metodo ajax get

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Boa tarde, eu tenho o seguinte pedaço de codigo:

```
function getData(){

    var url = "http://teste.com";
    var data = "";

    $.get(url, function(response){

    serverResponse = response;

        for(i in response.content){


            data +='\
            <tr>\
                <td>'+response.content[i].TesteId+'</td>\
                <td>'+response.content[i].TesteNome+'</td>\
                <td>'+response.content[i].TesteEmail+'</td>\
           </tr>';
        }

        $('#corpotabela').empty();
        $('#corpotabela').append(data);

        var width = new Array();
        $(".table-body tr:eq(0)").find('td').each(function (position){
            width[position] = $(this).outerWidth();
        });
        $(".table-header tr").find('th').each(function (position){
            $(this).css("width", width[position]+2);
        });

    });
}
```

Porem, para conseguir fazer essa requisição eu preciso enviar um token no header. Eu consigo fazer isso utilizando esse metodo jQuery?

Comment: Testa passar um objeto de configuração com `{url: url, beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Token', 'meu-valor');}`.

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar fazer algo assim

```
$.ajax({
   url : myurl,
   headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token' : token
   });
```

Mais informações de como fazer isso, leia o doc [$.ajax();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)